# Convert systemtime to filetime (Python)

Tags: python, filetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datetime to filetime (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408077/datetime-to-filetime-python)

I'm having trouble converting systemtime to filetime on windows. I will be glad if anyone will help me or give me some guides. Thanks!

Input: Mon, 13 August 2007 00:13:40 UTC
Output: CD4E55C3:01C7DD3E

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What is your input, and what exactly should be your output?

Comment: answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408077/datetime-to-filetime-python/6545835#6545835)