# python convert filetime to datetime for dates before 1970

Tags: python, datetime, filetime

I need to convert filetime to datetime. I am using this code [filetime.py](http://reliablybroken.com/b/wp-content/filetimes.py/%22filetime.py%22), from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/python-initialize-a-datetime-object-with-seconds-since-epoch/%22here2%22) as mentioned in this thread [Datetime to filetime (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408077/datetime-to-filetime-python).

In the code

```
EPOCH_AS_FILETIME = 116444736000000000  # January 1, 1970 as MS file time
HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS = 10000000

def filetime_to_dt(ft):
    """Converts a Microsoft filetime number to a Python datetime. The new datetime object is time zone-naive but is equivalent to tzinfo=utc.

    >>> filetime_to_dt(116444736000000000)
    datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    """
    # Get seconds and remainder in terms of Unix epoch
    (s, ns100) = divmod(ft - EPOCH_AS_FILETIME, HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS)
    # Convert to datetime object
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s)
    # Add remainder in as microseconds. Python 3.2 requires an integer
    dt = dt.replace(microsecond=(ns100 // 10))
    return dt
```

`datetime.utcfromtimestamp` does not take negative value on windows system, so I can't convert filetime before Jan 1st 1970. But I can convert dates before 1970 on Mac using the exact same code (reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/python-initialize-a-datetime-object-with-seconds-since-epoch/%22here2%22)). Is there any workaround for windows?

Comment: So all you mean is that you want to convert some epoch time in normal date time right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a `timedelta` to a reference date you can use any date formula you'd like. `timedelta` is allowed to be positive or negative.

```
def filetime_to_dt(ft):
    us = (ft - EPOCH_AS_FILETIME) // 10
    return datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds = us)
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp), you have to use:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(s, datetime.timezone.utc)
```

instead of:

```
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s)
```

Comment: sorry, I am using `import datetime datetime.timezone.utc` give the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timezone' ". Why is that?

Comment: @Echo: Maybe you are not using Python 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2

Answer (score 0):

first you need to convert it to a recognizable filetime format like this:

```
>>> dwLowDateTime = 0x0F7297A80
>>> dwHighDateTime = 0x1C3F10F << 32
>>> ft = (dwLowDateTime & 0xFFFFFFFF) | dwHighDateTime
127210265370000000
```

and then use this script, it converts filetime to datetime and vice versa https://gist.github.com/Mostafa-Hamdy-Elgiar/9714475f1b3bc224ea063af81566d873

```
>>> filetime_to_dt(ft)
2004-02-12 02:28:57
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `timedelta`s to add/subtract/divide between time frames:

```py
FILE_TIME_EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1)
FILE_TIME_MICROSECOND = 10 # FILETIME counts 100 nanoseconds intervals = 0.1 microseconds, so 10 of those are 1 microsecond

def convert_from_file_time(file_time):
    microseconds_since_file_time_epoch = file_time // FILE_TIME_MICROSECOND
    return FILE_TIME_EPOCH + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=microseconds_since_file_time_epoch)
```

And the other side of this is:

```py
def convert_to_file_time(date_time):
    microseconds_since_file_time_epoch = (date_time - FILE_TIME_EPOCH) // datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)
    return microseconds_since_file_time_epoch * FILE_TIME_MICROSECOND
```